# How to Invoke two or more ant targets from eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, build, eclipse-plugin

I use ant plugin for eclipse.

from comman line I can write

```
ant clean all
```

What analog can I use with plugin?

**UPDATE**

[image]

what I can click after?

[image]

Comment: Use depends on target.

Comment: can you explain more in detail

Answer (score 2):

You can create one of the target and specify depends property of the targets you want to execute.
Refer to below sample code

`<project name="some name" default="executeMultipleTargets">`

`<target name="executeMultipleTargets" depends="myTarget1,target2,target3,clean" >`

`<echo>Build Successfull....</echo>`

`</target>`

`</project>`

Answer (score 1):

Ant is considered an external tool. So you do not have a *run configuration* but an *external tool configuration* for ant runs. There even exists a sub-point "Ant Builds" in that window.

It is very strange that you do not have the option *run as ant build* when right-clicking an ant build file. I can only assume, you do not have the appropriate plugin (although that is installed by default).

But maybe you are satisfid by just creating an external tool configuration for running ant.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify multiple targets in Ant GUI: open your build.xml file and in outline view right click desired target. Then select "Run as -> Ant build..." and check all desired targets.

Comment: That is strange... when I open build.xml file and view it in editor, I have "Ant build..." option in my "Run as" context menu. Which perspective do you use?

Comment: java ee or java and other I see this

Comment: What if you right-click on build.xml file in Navigator view, can you perhaps then select "Run as -> Ant build..."?

Answer (score 0):

You can go on eclipse-> external tools configurations, select in Targets tab your preferable ant targets and be executed in order.